# How to acces controls from another page in asp.net using jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have used page1.aspx & page2.aspx.

In page1.aspx I have used following code,

```
<div id="resultdiv" >
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In page2.aspx, i have load the page1.aspx page on the div of page2.aspx page.
the code is,

```
<script type="text/javascript" >    
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#result').load('page1.aspx #resultdiv');
});
```

```
<div id="result">
```

my question is, how to access page1.aspx controls(textbox) from page2.aspx.

pls clarify my doubt. i'm new to jquery.

Comment: What do you mean by "*in page2.aspx, i have load the page1.aspx page on the div of page2.aspx*" ? Can you post your markup ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are not using the MasterPage in your solution ?

Comment: Do you want the value in the textbox or you are trying to do something with the texbox itself?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what you want to ask but whatever i understand i think you want to get controls of another page....
you can try this below code

```
function load_controls()
{
$.get("page1.aspx", function( data ) {
  $("#result" ).html(data);  
});
}
```

and then call this function where ever you want....hope will help you and if you have any query then just put comment....

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below in page2.aspx:

```
<script>
function save() {
$('#resultdiv input').each(function () {
alert($(this).val());
}); 
}
</script>
```